# Deleted? Items show up in Export

Tags: export

I export a list from my sharepoint and items in the excel show up that are not in the list, where are these coming from?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps things that were filtered out in a view are showing up.
In Sharepoint go in:

Document Library Settings > Modify View > Filter.

If there is a filter it might be filtering out certain items.